# External Custom library for Gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am building a SpringBoot application in which i want to handle some of the cross cutting concerns like logging, caching, persistence in to a project on its own so in future other rest spring boot components can adopt it and use it as a dependency.

I am using Gradle for dependency  management. My question is :-

1. How can i manage this concerns without publishing it to the public artifactory.
2. If i have to publish then which is the free artifactory i can use for my development practice
3. If creating jar is an option as a temp solution then how can it be achieved via gradle. Most of the examples over the internet is for creating the executable jar files.
4. What are the other options i can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i manage this concerns without publishing it to the public artifactory.

Publishing has to happen regardless where it will be published to. You can use a private solution such as [Nexus Repository](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository).

> If i have to publish then which is the free artifactory i can use for my development practice

For development, you can simply publish to your local Maven repository. This is typically `~/.m2`. Using the [Maven Publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin, you can easily publish locally by invoking the [`publishToMavenLocal` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks).

> If creating jar is an option as a temp solution then how can it be achieved via gradle. Most of the examples over the internet is for creating the executable jar files.

Since you're creating a Spring Boot library, use the [Java Library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugin to create the JAR artifact and in combination with the Maven Publish plugin to publish.

In the end, there are 2-3 key components that get published when using Gradle:

1. JAR artifact
2. `pom.xml`: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html
3. Gradle Module Metadata: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_gradle_module_metadata.html

Comment: Just thought to update this thread with my latest findings. Jfrog provides a open source version of their artifactories to use and test. I was able to install in on my machine and use it an external repository for managing my artifacts.